# Want to copy first row of each sheet of multiple Excel files to another Excel file

Tags: excel

There is 27 Excel files (Workbooks) and each Excel file would have 5 tabs (Sheets) or 2.

I want to copy each Sheet first Row of every files (27 Workbooks including their Sheets) to another new Excel Sheet (combine on Sheet) to check whether each file have same header or not.

Comment: And what your problem is? What have you tried?

Comment: [This link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/237276-making-same-change-multiple-excel-files.html) should get you started. Please show us what you have tried before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is few things you might need;

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rowCopy As Range
For Each sFilename In listOfFiles
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilename)
    Set rowCopy = wb.Range([rangewheretocopy])

    rowCopy.Copy

    shWhereYouCopyItAll.Range([targetrange]).PasteSpecial
Next
```

Assuming hypothetical list of files `listOfFiles` which you can foreach for string `sFilename` in order to open the Workbooks. Then set Range object `rowCopy` to the range where that one row is, then call your local sheet Range `PasteSpecial` function.

You might need to learn more and above piece of code will not do the work youre asking for. I am expecting you to put some effort into programming this aswell.